# Symfony is changing where it's looking for assets depending on url

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

Symfony looks to be looking for assets in a relative location based on the url path I navigate to. The assets load and are applied correctly when I navigate to a "first-level" path such as `example.com/mpre`, `example.com/test`, `example.com/foo`, but then all of my assets 404 when I navigate to a "second-level" url such as `example.com/mpre/test`, `example.com/test/foo`, `example.com/foo/bar`. Why is this? Is there a way to get the framework to look in one spot for the assets regardless of the url?

I have 2 urls

```
example.com/mpre
example.com/mpre/test
```

My assets (css, js) load fine on the first url, `example.com/mpre`, but then all of them 404 when I navigate to the second url, `example.com/mpre/test`

When I go into the inspector on each page to see the path to the assets, I see the following:

```
example.com/bundles/app/css/023f7f6_style.css_4.css       //example.com/mpre   200 OK response
example.com/mpre/bundles/app/css/c8b625f_style.css_3.css     //example.com/mpre/test   404 Not Found response
```

In `config.yml` I have the following line for assetic:

```
assetic:
    write_to:   %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/app/
```

#### Additional Information

- I am **not** using the `cssrewrite` filter

#### Edit 1

- I installed Symfony 2.3 via composer
- Im including the css in base.html.twig and using assetic to compile
  them

  ```
  {% stylesheets
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/css/bootstrap_loader.css.scss'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/css/stately/*'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/css/style.css.scss'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/css/learners.css'
  %}
  ```
- The paths are standard routes. Each path corresponds to a controller
  action which renders a view
- Here is what the view looks like when the assets 404
  [image]
- Here is the dump of `./app/console config:dump-reference assetic`

Default configuration for extension with alias: "assetic"

assetic:
    debug:                %kernel.debug%
    use_controller:
        enabled:              %kernel.debug%
        profiler:             false
    read_from:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    write_to:             %assetic.read_from%
    java:                 /usr/bin/java
    node:                 /usr/bin/node
        node_paths:           []
        ruby:                 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
        sass:                 /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/sass
        variables:

```
    # Prototype
    name:                 []
bundles:

    # Defaults:
    - FrameworkBundle
    - SecurityBundle
    - TwigBundle
    - MonologBundle
    - SwiftmailerBundle
    - AsseticBundle
    - DoctrineBundle
    - SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
    - AppBundle
    - LswMemcacheBundle
    - WebProfilerBundle
    - SensioDistributionBundle
    - SensioGeneratorBundle
assets:

    # Prototype
    name:
        inputs:               []
        filters:              []
        options:

            # Prototype
            name:                 []
filters:

    # Prototype
    name:                 []
workers:
    cache_busting:
        enabled:              false
twig:
    functions:

        # Prototype
        name:                 []
```

#### Edit 2

I've found the source of the problem. The link path was relative, so I changed it to use the baseUrl. `<script src="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/bundles/app{{ asset_url }}"></script>` and everything works great.

Comment: How did you install Symfony? Did you do it over Composer? If so, what package/version did you install?

I've never had to manually change the write_to parameter.

What does your view look like? How are you including the css? and are the paths you have above setup as standard routes on a Controller? or something different?

Comment: What is the output of **./app/console config:debug assetic**? I'm assuming there is an issue between the **write_to** and **read_from** settings. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Comment: I've added the requested information in the original question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is an issue with your the **write_to** setting.

Try these settings and see what happens.

```
assetic:
    read_from: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web'
    write_to:  '%assetic.read_from%'
```

These should be the default assetic config settings for **read_from** and **write_to**.

Your settings show `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/app/`. Assetic will generate the bundles folders automatically, so setting up your own `bundles` folder is probably causing unexpected results.

In `bundles/`, `app` corresponds to your bundle `AppBundle`. A bundle named `FooBundle` would have it's assets in `web/bundles/foo/` etc.

Make sure you clear your Symfony cache after making changes to the config file.